# laravel ajax function doesn't return a value

Tags: ajax, laravel

Hello I'm working on laravel and trying to make a ajax action

```
function jsfunctionrr(value){
  var value_parts =  value.split("+");
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/getpoinsts',
    data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        'name': value_parts[1]
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#pointsValue').append(total_points);
    }
});
```

and the controller function

```
public function getpoinsts(Request $request)
{
    $user_points_parts = DB::table('clients_points')->where('user_id', $request->name)->get;
    $total_points = 0;

    foreach ($user_points_parts as $points_part) {
        $total_points += $points_part->points;
    }

    return response()->json($total_points);
}
```

and the route

```
Route::post('/getpoinsts', 'LoyalityController@getpoinsts');
```

but I get no value in back any one know why ??

Comment: Have you tried putting in an 'error' function within your AJAX call to see if your call is not successful?

Comment: Are you at least getting a 200 response?

Comment: how can I do that

Comment: I get this Empty string passed to getElementById(). on changing the select

Comment: There are a number of issues with your code.  Firstly, is `points_part` a column name in the `clients_points` table? If so, are you just trying to get the sum of those columns?

Comment: okay I will edit , what is next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issue in your code that I've noticed:

1. `->get;` should be `get();`
2. There might be an issue with trying to convert a number to json.
3. In your ajax method you're referencing `total_points` but it isn't defined anywhere.

Try changing your controller method to:

```
public function getpoinsts(Request $request)
{
    $total_points = DB::table('clients_points')->where('user_id', $request->name)->sum('points');

    return response()->json(compact('total_points'));
}
```

and your ajax method to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/getpoinsts',
    data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        'name': value_parts[1]
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#pointsValue').append(data.total_points);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!